# Prevent repeating logic with DRF and Django

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and Django Rest Framework with the Serializer Extensions Mixin to expand fields. I have some calculated fields that I only want to call sometimes to minimize hits on my DB. However, I need to be able to call these calculations in both templates (i.e. through the models) and through the serializers (i.e. using DRF's `serializers.MethodField` + Serializer Extensions Mixin expand feature).

As it stands, the only way I can figure out how to do this is by including the logic in both `models.py` AND `serializers.py`, as I can't use `serializers.MethodField` to call the method that I created in `models.py.` Not very DRY and a huge potential flaw.

When I try to call the method via `serializers.MethodField` it simply returns the method object and doesn't run the method itself (i.e. `"<property object at 0x7f18d78de9a8>"`).

Is there any way to force DRF to run a method that is in `models.py` only when triggered? If I include it as a `serializers.ReadOnlyField`, it will trigger every time the serializer is called, which I don't want. However, Serializer Extensions Mixin doesn't support `serializers.ReadOnlyField.`

I suppose I could make a serializer specifically for this instance, but that seems overly complicated.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is certainly possible to call your model methods in serializers. Show the code that you have written to have an answer that makes sense to you and anyone who sees this post in future.